Default Laravel Breeze returns errors about required fields
I'm refreshing my laravel skills because it has been 2 years since I used it. I would say some things have changed and I'm struggling with some of those.
I want to register users and looking at Laravel Breeze tutorials, it can already be done with just the default setup which comes with Breeze.
However, I'm not able to register a new user because of an error message I get for all my fields, telling me the field is required. Well, I can assure you I do fill out the form with correct data but it would still give me the error and it seems I'm the only one who bumps into this issue..
My Blade file:
<x-guest-layout>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
        @csrf

        <!-- Name -->
        <div>
            <x-input-label for="name" :value="__('Name')"  class="text-white" />
            <x-text-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full bg-gray-100 border-b-0" type="text" name="name" :value="old('name')" required autofocus autocomplete="name" />
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('name')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Username | This will be visible to the public -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-input-label for="username" :value="__('Username')"  class="text-white" />
            <x-text-input id="username" class="block mt-1 w-full bg-gray-100 border-b-0" type="text" name="username" :value="old('username')" required autofocus autocomplete="username" />
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('username')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Email Address -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-input-label for="email" :value="__('Email')" class="text-white" />
            <x-text-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full bg-gray-100 border-b-0" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" required autocomplete="username" />
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('email')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Password -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-input-label for="password" :value="__('Password')" class="text-white" />

            <x-text-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full border-b-0"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            required 
                            autocomplete="new-password" />

            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Confirm Password -->
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-input-label for="password_confirmation" :value="__('Confirm Password')" class="text-white" />

            <x-text-input id="password_confirmation" class="block mt-1 w-full border-b-0"
                            type="password"
                            name="password_confirmation" 
                            required 
                            autocomplete="new-password" />

            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password_confirmation')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
            <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-white hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-gray-100 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-800" href="{{ route('login') }}">
                {{ __('Already registered?') }}
            </a>

            <x-primary-button class="ms-4">
                {{ __('Register') }}
            </x-primary-button>
        </div>
    </form>
</x-guest-layout>

My RegisteredAuthController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     */
    public function create(): View
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'lowercase', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:'.User::class],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        dd('halllooooooo');

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        dd($user);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(route('dashboard', absolute: false));
    }
}

User Model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
        ];
    }
}

If you want to see me reproduce the steps you can watch this loom:
https://www.loom.com/share/d6bf15d9d3ff46929cbad9ba41fb2019?sid=5515dcee-80db-4fff-9613-cdfb446bfbc9

Can use add your User model code?

@JayDev95, sure I can!

What does the method output if inside the store() method, you add dd($request->all()) right at the top. Make it the first time called inside the method.

@JayDev95, it returns a token which seems valid, but no further data

If you inspect the DOM in your browser, do you see all the inputs rendered correctly with the correct name attributes?

@JonWhite Good shout! It looks like the inputs are rendered but without the name tags! This could be the reason why it fails. Thanks for the clue

@JonWhite Yep, that was the problem! Couldn't get it fixed but once I cleared the views, the name attributes were added to the rendered inputs and the registration succeeded!
Thanks for the help!

Glad I could help

For anyone else who comes across this issue:
When updating views in Laravel, often cached views can cause the browser to fail to render what's actually in your code.
In this case, inspect the DOM in your browser to see if the "name" attributes on each of the form inputs has correctly rendered.
If not, clear the view cache using
php artisan view:clear

Then reload the page and inspect the form inputs. You should now see the names correctly rendered and the form input should be passed to the controller
